# Understanding a diagram on Convolution

Tags: functions, convolution, big-picture

Could someone please explain what is happening at the "f*g" row and below?
The image is located [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aComparison_convolution_correlation.svg) as linked from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). I want to teach myself about Fourier Transforms / Series, and I've come across "convolutions." I just want to make sure I understand this diagram correctly as I try to get a feel for what the function returns are.

Thanks.

Comment: You might find it useful to have a look at the answers to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255929/can-someone-intuitively-explain-what-the-convolution-integral-is?rq=1) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284794/intuition-behind-the-convolution-of-two-functions?rq=1) question.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1405/235) on dsp.SE.

Answer (score 0):

As you saw in the Wikipedia entry, the definition of convolution is $(f \ast g) (t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\tau) g(t - \tau) d\tau.$

Now, notice that, in the example, $f$ is simply (assuming the constant value is $1$)$f(t) = \begin{cases}1, & a < t < b \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Hence, the above integral becomes
$$(f \ast g) (t) = \int_{a}^{b} g(t - \tau) d\tau,$$
which is just the area below the graph of $g(t - \tau)$ for $\tau \in (a,b)$. Now the drawings below the $f \ast g$ row show the overlapping of the functions $g(t-  \tau)$ and $f(\tau)$ for increasing values of $t$. By analyzing the behavior (first increasing, then decreasing) of the highlighted area below the graph of $g$, we can understand the behavior of the convolution.